# Onkeydown failed to work on (screen touch )

Tags: android, jquery

I have a textbox with a default value that onkeydown it should cleared the default value but it seems I'm not able to fix it please help me on this.

This is my script

```
$('input').keydown(function () {
    this.value = "" 
});

$('input').blur(function () {
    If (this.value = "") {
        this.value = this.title;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you should use placeholder attribute instead and read some basic tutos about javascript. BTW, are you implicitely meaning your code works on non touch device?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `focus()` not `keydown()` for clearing the default text, otherwise it won't be possible to type anything in to the box. Secondly, javascript is case sensitive, so it should be `if`, not `If`, and you need to use `==` for the comparison operator.

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    this.value = "" 
});

$('input').blur(function () {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.value = this.title;
    }
});
```

Comment: U ar grt Let me try that if it will be the solution. Thanks for your answer